# Filtering data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with pandas 0.13.0

I have a data frame(a) with 2.5 million records

I want to exclude some hundreds of records applying two conditions simoultaneusly: only the records that fulfill the 2 conditions at the same time.

I want to see how many records I will exclude when applying both conditions:

```
len(a)  
2523250
b=a[(a.cond1=='120.A') & (a.cond2==2012)]
len(b)
6010
```

But when I apply the conditions to obtain the final dataframe:

```
c=a[(a.cond1!='120.A') & (a.cond2!=2012)]
len(c)
2214968
```

In the second case '&' is working like and 'OR'
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the len match the second condition if you do this: `a[~((a.cond1=='120.A') & (a.cond2==2012))]`?

Comment: Yes, it works thanksbut why my original approach doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Review [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). The logical negation of `&` is not simply switching the `==` with `!=`, you must also swap `&` with `|`, because you want the rows where either `cond1 != '120.A'` *or* `cond2 != 2012`, i.e., you want to exclude a row if ONE of the `!=` conditions is true because that makes the original `&` statement `False`.

@EdChum's comment above is equivalent to

```
c=a[(a.cond1!='120.A') | (a.cond2!=2012)]
```